# Object detection on lidar data

Tags: object-detection, lidar

I have lidar data and stitched 360-degree images. My task is to detect the individual object and localize them on the lidar data.

I have done object detection on stitched images but am unable to map those objects into lidar data.

Any help will be highly appreciated.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: [This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56629509/using-lidar-images-and-camera-images-to-perform-object-detection) might be a similar question and provide you with an answer.